# how to install ubuntu on an existing ubuntu machine

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP-Laptop (AMD). I have had problems with booting the machine where it gets stuck at the purple ubunti screen.
I made a boot-able USB and did a trial run to check for the blinking problem during boot-up. With the boot-able USB I did not face the blinking boot problem.
I installed ubuntu from this USB, it created a separate partition and installed the OS but when I boot it still boots with the earlier versions.
It does not show this version in the options that one gets during boot-up.
How do I get it to boot from the version that was installed from USB.

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: running sudo update-grub solved the problem - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At boot you should see a grub screen where you can choose from the different systems. Probably your grub does not recognize the new installation properly. You should run 
`sudo update-grub`
then reboot and check if you see a grub menu where you can select the new installation

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hold <kbd>escape</kbd> when you are booting and a menu will appear.
Select the function key (ie. <kbd>F3</kbd>) for 'boot menu' or equivalent. 
It should give you options to select which partition/OS you want to load.

Answer (score 0):

run this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y boot-repair boot-info
```

allow the app to finish then reboot

on reboot grub should be repaired and you should see both systems in grub.